# When does the non-static block get executed in java?

Tags: java, static, block, non-static

I expected that non-static blocks always execute at the time of object creation. But in the following example I called the static method but the non-static block executed. I've not created any object so why does the non-static block execute?

```
class Example {
  static void Mark() {
    System.out.println("Mark method");
    {
      System.out.println("Hello");
    }
  }
}   

public class StaticObject {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example.Mark();
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Mark method
Hello
```

Comment: Without indentation this is essentially unreadable.

Comment: You just have a block inside a static method, which doesn't match your question text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have a non-static initialization block in your example. A block inside of a method is just code that gets executed as part of the method. (Nested code blocks introduce a new scope, so you can create variables that are not visible outside of the block.)

It's only an initializer if it's within the class but outside of a method declaration. If you change the code to move the block to outside of any method:

```
class Example {
    static void Mark() {
        System.out.println("Mark method");
    }

    // now it's an instance initializer
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

then you should see the instance initializer execute when the object is instantiated. If you don't instantiate an object, as in your example, then the instance initializer won't get run.